# How to log the time it took to for a view to load

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Is it possible to determine how long it took for a SwiftUI view to have loaded? When I say loaded, I mean all sub views within the view are fully rendered on the screen. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can get the time when the view is initialized, and the time when [`onAppear(perform:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/AnyView/onAppear(perform:)) is called. You can then calculate the difference in seconds.

The `init()` is called when the view is trying to be created/initialized. This will be the start date.

[`onAppear(perform:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/AnyView/onAppear(perform:)) is only called once the view has been rendered onto the screen. This means that you know all subviews have also been loaded, since the view will be a composition of its subviews. When this is called, this will be the end date.

Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    private let creationDate: Date

    init() {
        creationDate = Date()
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello world!")

            Text(String(timeConsumingCalculation()))
        }
        .onAppear {
            let interval = Date().timeIntervalSince(creationDate)
            print(interval)
        }
    }

    private func timeConsumingCalculation() -> Int {
        (1 ... 10_000_000).reduce(0, +)
    }
}
```

Result (when I ran it, will vary):

> ```
> 4.901658892631531
> ```

Comment: I tried this approach, but I noticed onAppear and init get invoked multiple times, making the latency calculation incorrect relative to what the user sees. Ideally I want to calculate how long it took for the parent view to fully render.

Comment: @aamirnshah To fix that a [mre] would help. I would not expect the init and onAppear to be called multiple times, that may be a problem with the view's identity (e.g. with `.id(...)`). It may even warrant a 2nd question, because from the question you have - this is solved. It's just not working in a more complex project because of other issues.